# Angular 2 \ Node Dependencies

Tags: node.js, angular

When I tried to Install node dependencies again I got the below error. 
I deleted the node modules folder and installed again and it installed correctly but I want to know why this error has occurred. Please help me on this.

**D-4417845 MINGW64 /d/Project_Worksapce/angular2-reddit-master/angular2-reddit-master**
*$ npm install*

ng-book2-reddit@1.0.0 D:\Project_Worksapce\angular2-reddit-master\angular2-reddit-master

+-- concurrently@1.0.0

+-- es6-shim@0.33.13

+-- live-server@0.9.2

+-- reflect-metadata@0.1.2

+-- rxjs@5.0.0-beta.0

+-- systemjs@0.19.6

+-- typescript@1.8.10

`-- zone.js@0.5.10

npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393
npm ERR! argv "D:\Node\node.exe" "D:\Node\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! node v6.10.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! path D:\Project_Worksapce\angular2-reddit-master\angular2-reddit-master\node_modules.staging\angular2-751451fd
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! syscall rename

npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'D:\Project_Worksapce\angular2-reddit-master\angular2-reddit-master\node_modules.staging\angular2-751451fd' -> 'D:\Project_Worksapce\angular2-reddit-master\angular2-reddit-master\node_modules\angular2'
npm ERR!     at destStatted (D:\Node\node_modules\npm\lib\install\action\finalize.js:25:7)
npm ERR!     at D:\Node\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:264:29
npm ERR!     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:123:15)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'D:\Project_Worksapce\angular2-reddit-master\angular2-reddit-master\node_modules.staging\angular2-751451fd' -> 'D:\Project_Worksapce\angular2-reddit-master\angular2-reddit-master\node_modules\angular2'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!  { Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'D:\Project_Worksapce\angular2-reddit-master\angular2-reddit-master\node_modules.staging\angular2-751451fd' -> 'D:\Project_Worksapce\angular2-reddit-master\angular2-reddit-master\node_modules\angular2'
npm ERR!     at destStatted (D:\Node\node_modules\npm\lib\install\action\finalize.js:25:7)
npm ERR!     at D:\Node\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:264:29
npm ERR!     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:123:15)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'D:\Project_Worksapce\angular2-reddit-master\angular2-reddit-master\node_modules.staging\angular2-751451fd' -> 'D:\Project_Worksapce\angular2-reddit-master\angular2-reddit-master\node_modules\angular2'
npm ERR!     at Error (native) parent: 'ng-book2-reddit' }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     D:\Project_Worksapce\angular2-reddit-master\angular2-reddit-master\npm-debug.log

Comment: Everything is in the error message, you probably did an npm install using administrator rights and now it needs to remove/rename folders but it doesn't have permissions for that.

Comment: Supamiu , I installed with administrator privileges only but when I tried to install the dependencies again I am getting the error so I deleted the node modules folder and then installed again and its working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we already have node modules then when we give "npm install" it will check all the dependencies and if it is already present then it will ignore and install only those which is not present. Sometime it will throw such an error.Not sure why it happens but I deleted the node modules folder and then installed again and its work perfectly.